# Online accounts with Amazon Cloud Drive

Tags: nautilus, online-accounts, amazon, online-storage

"Online accounts" includes nautilus-backed cloud drive support for google drive.  This is very handy.

Is there an equivalent plug-in to provide support for Amazon cloud drive?